# Mysql syntax error when generating query from a script

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that generates a query, the query is then executed using `mysql_query()`

It shows an error I can't work out...If I echo the sql statement and execute it on phpmyadmin it works perfectly.

```
function magikarp($table, $arr)
{
$data=array();
$campos="";
$val="";

for($c=0;$c<count($arr);++$c)
{
    $var=make_safe(current($arr));
    if($var!="")
    {
        $campos=$campos.key($arr).",";
        $val=$val."".current($arr).",";
        $data[key($arr)]=$var;
    }
    next($arr);
}

$campos[ strlen($campos)-1]=''; //THIS IS FOR THE EXTRA COMA AT THE END
$val[ strlen($val)-1]='';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($campos) VALUES ($val)"; 

//trim($sql);
echo $sql;

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
return $data;

}


IT ECHO
INSERT INTO clientes (cedula,nombre,apellido) VALUES ('123','5454','51515')
```

Comment: In India sintax is the name of company for water storage tanks....

Comment: @Wazzzy that may well be, but the OP seems to be from a country where the official language is Spanish.

Comment: @Verbeia That was just funny part added to the question...No issues with language and country...I appreciate OP being from Spain...

Comment: yes i speak spanish, i have 3 hours trying to find out what is wrong... :(

Comment: Show us the syntax error that you get. By the way, the line `trim($sql);` does nothing since trim returns the new string rather than altering the variable passed. It would be `$sql=trim($sql);` but there's nothing to trim anyway.

Comment: error: "Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

the trim() was from a comment.

Comment: That error message is very strange. Are you absolutely **sure** that that SQL you're echoing is the same SQL you execute?

Comment: yes it is strange, i post the SQL that is echoed in the code.

Comment: @Wazzzy I figured, but it did read a bit like you were mocking the OP for Indian English instead of just editing the post.

Comment: i was thinking this is because of binary safety bug

Comment: i was thinking this is because of a binary safety bug in my code... but i cant find it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was some hidden characters in my text editor.